# .git/refs/heads/ folder has no content after git fetch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins git plugin to checkout a branch and want to use that as committish object for rest of the operations. After checkout, when i execute rev-parse command, it throws error

```
$/c/apps/Jenkins/workspace/Test/testCheckoutStage ((cbebe2c...))                                                                  
$ git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- <git-url>/~opaliwal/opaliwal.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 

$/c/apps/Jenkins/workspace/Test/testCheckoutStage ((cbebe2c...))                                                                  
$ git rev-parse temp                                                                                                                                              
fatal: ambiguous argument 'temp': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.                                                                               
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:                                                                                                             
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'                                                                                                                    
temp                             
$/c/apps/Jenkins/workspace/Test/testCheckoutStage((cbebe2c...))
```

When i check .git/refs/heads folder, there is nothing and rev-parse command will fail in that condition as per [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem)

Any idea how to fetch these heads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all perfectly normal.  The name you want is not `temp` but rather `origin/temp`, or better—because it's unambiguous—the full name `refs/remotes/origin/temp`.

---

Your `git fetch` command is shown above:

> ```
> git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune --
>     <git-url>/~opaliwal/opaliwal.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

(I've broken one line into two just for display purposes here).  This fetch provides a *refspec*—a pair of ref names separated by a colon, and optionally prefixed with a plus sign `+` that is used here—and this refspec determines which refs will be written into your local repository based on which refs appear in the remote repository.

In this case, the source refs are `refs/heads/*`: all branch names.  These source refs will be copied to `refs/remotes/origin/*`, which are *remote-tracking names* rather than branch names.  The leading plus sign `+` sets the force flag: it directs Git to overwrite any previous remote-tracking names, even if the operation is not a fast-forward.  Last, the `--prune` option directs Git to *remove* any remote-tracking names that were not copied during this process.  (Such names are presumably stale: leftovers from a previous fetch, where the branch name in the other Git has been deleted since then.)

This means if the source repository—the other Git—has a branch named `temp`, the destination repository, receiving the fetch, will wind up with a remote-tracking name spelled `origin/temp`, or `refs/remotes/origin/temp`.  The fully-qualified name guarantees that you get this one, rather than (e.g.) a tag named `origin/temp`, should someone do something rather silly and create that.

You will probably find that `.git/refs/remotes/` is empty here too.  That's normal: refs are not necessarily stored in individual files.  Sometimes they are, and sometimes, instead, they are *packed* into `.git/packed-refs`, which is a simple flat-file text database with one ref per line.  (Annotated tags stored in the packed refs file wind up with a second entry as well, for efficiency.)  This is why you are supposed to use `git rev-parse`, rather than looking for individual files: rev-parse knows the rules about whether and when to use entries in the database.

Comment: Will origin/<tag> also work the same way? Is there a way to use a committish that works for a commit, a branch and a tag with the kind of fetch i am doing?

Comment: Generally not. When copying tags, you use `git fetch --tags`, which is similar to `git fetch <remote> refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` which keeps the tags un-renamed so that their tags become your tags. When not using `--tags` or `--no-tags`, the way `git fetch` works is complicated and hard to describe, but the outcome is that you get some but not all tags, with no renaming.

Comment: The best way to deal with *one specific commit* is to use its hash ID. Unfortunately, without setting particular configuration entries on the server side Git, there's no way to supply a raw hash ID as the source of a `git fetch`. But if you know the hash ID you should have—if that's available somewhere—you can run your `git fetch` and see if you got that hash ID. If so, proceed; if not, complain that you can't seem to obtain that commit.

Comment: Finally, if you're not actually *using* a repository for its repository-ness, consider (a) not using Git at all or (b) using a mirror clone. The mirror clone can't be developed in, but if a commit is going to be reachable in the source, it will be reachable in the mirror clone too. (For (a), have the source Git run `git archive` on the commit you're interested in.) Note: I have no idea how to do any of this in Jenkins itself. From my interactions with Jenkins, it appears to me that Jenkins was written by someone who hates users and wants them to be miserable. :-)

Comment: (As an example, I note that we had some longstanding bugs with tests running on Jenkins that turned out to be problematic because **Jenkins set all signals to `SIG_IGN`** before launching a process. This is amazingly wrong Unix behavior.)